# Vscode gives error when using function from import in extension

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

Right, so, the title isn't really any good. But basically the problem I have is that, while trying to make my own version of a plugin I use, I have been unable to run it.

What makes it stop working seems to be using a function imported from another local file  (In typescript). I have tried everything I could think of, such as, copying a working extension and just replacing the code, changing the compiler settings copying the official extension example github. As well as changing the functions between async and not async.

I also tried running the original plugin from source to test if it was something with my environment. But that did work. Soooo... I have 0 clue about what could be the cause (Except for the imported functions).

(as I don't know what causes it I don't really know what parts would be helpful, so everything down below is of uncertain necessary level, I have also barely done anything with typescript or vscode extensions before)

The error message

```
Activating extension 'Kycklingris.vscode-profiles' failed: The "original" argument must be of type function. Received undefined.
```

My main extension .ts file, it works with test commented out but not with it in, and test is completely empty.

```
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { GetProfiles, GetSettings, GetWorkspaceSettings, SetProfiles, SetWorkspaceSettings } from "./settings";
import { CreateProfile, ApplyProfile, EditProfile, DeleteProfile, PickProfile, test } from './utils';

// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    
    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json

    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.commands.registerCommand("vscode-profiles.Apply", Apply),
        vscode.commands.registerCommand("vscode-profiles.Create", Create),
        vscode.commands.registerCommand("vscode-profiles.Edit", Edit),
        vscode.commands.registerCommand("vscode-profiles.Delete", Delete),
    );
}
export function deactivate() {}

async function Apply() {
    test();
    //let id = await PickProfile();
    //ApplyProfile(id);
}

async function Create() {
    //CreateProfile();
}

async function Edit() {
    //let id = await PickProfile();
    //EditProfile(id);
}

async function Delete() {
    //let id = await PickProfile();
    //DeleteProfile(id);
}
```

From my package.json, I have installed all of them, tho not globally

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^12.20.19",
        "@types/vscode": "^1.59.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.1",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "typescript": "^4.5.0-dev.20210814"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "sqlite": "^4.0.23",
        "sqlite3": "^5.0.2",
        "util": "^0.12.4",
        "vscode": "^1.1.37"
    }
```

aaaaaand my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true, /* enable all strict type-checking options */
        "alwaysStrict": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2019",
        "outDir": "out",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2019"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    },
    "include": [
        "./src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./test",
        "./node_modules",
        "./.vscode-test"
    ]
}
```

Edit:
What might be important from the utils file

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import { GetProfiles, GetSettings, SetProfiles, SetWorkspaceSettings, GetProfile, SetProfile } from "./settings";
import { Profile, Extension } from "./types";
import { UpdateExtensions, GetAllExtensions } from "./extensionUtil";

export async function test() {
    
}
```

and the directory structure is:

```
node_modules/
out/
    extension.js
    extension.js.map
    ...
src/
    extension.ts
    extensionUtil.ts
    settings.ts
    types.ts
    utils.ts
.eslintrc.json
package-lock.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the `utils` file content, the folder structure? Which extension has the utiil file?

Comment: @Max sorry for taking a while to do it, but I have updated it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readDir = promisify(fs.readdirectory);
```

Should have been

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readDir = promisify(fs.readdir);
```

I do not know the exact specifics of why this was a thing, as this was part of the code that I didn't write but rather kept.